# Angular Controller involving 'ui.state' throws error: Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have just started experimenting with the angular-ui-router from github to use states instead of the mess that is routing.  I have written a controller and included it in all my bundled files, html, etc. However, when I navigate to the page on my localhost, it throws the following error in the chrome console:  "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'WeatherCtrl' is not a function, got string".

The following is my angular code:

```
Kr.controller("WeatherCtrl", ['ui.state'])
   .config(['$stateProvider',
     function($stateProvider) {

       var weather = {
         name: 'weather',
         url: '/nws',
         abstract: true,
         templateUrl: 'partials/webtools/nws/weatherDefault.html'
       };

       var smallWeather = {
         name: 'smallWeather',
         url: '/nws/shortForecast',
         parent: weather,
         templateUrl: 'partials/webtools/nws/shortForecast'
       };

       var mediumWeather = {
         name: 'mediumWeather',
         url: '/nws/mediumForecast',
         parent: weather,
         templateUrl: 'partials/webtools/nws/mediumForecast'
       };

       var bigWeather = {
         name: 'bigWeather',
         url: '/nws/longForecast',
         parent: weather,
         templateUrl: 'partials/webtools/nws/longForecast'
       };

       $stateProvider
         .state(weather)
         .state(smallWeather)
         .state(mediumWeather)
         .state(bigWeather);
     }
   ]);
```

and this is the relevant html code:

```
<div ng-controller ="WeatherCtrl">
<div class="span11">
  <ul class="a-btn-group text-center">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
      <a ui-sref=".smallWeather" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> 6 to 10 Day Forecast</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
      <a ui-sref=".mediumWeather" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> 8 to 14 Day Forecast</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
      <a ui-sref=".bigWeather" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> Three Month Outlook</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p ui-sref=='weather'>Please select a Forecast Type using the buttons above</p>
</div>
```

Curiously enough, the paragraph element will display when the page has the state 'weather', but I can't be sure if this is because ui-sref is being ignored and the paragraph simply inserting itself as an independent element.  Also, I do recognize that the angular app has slightly funky syntax, but it seems correct according to the latest documentation of angular-ui-router.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

What does this string mean?

```
Kr.controller("WeatherCtrl", ['ui.state'])
```

I guess you try to define `WeatherCtrl` controller, but provided array `['ui.state']` instead of controller function.

Try this:

```
Kr.controller("WeatherCtrl", function($scope) {
   // Controller logic...
})
```

Comment: @Cain Mathis I was confused about that too. Also, it might be cleaner to not use ng-controller in the HTML template ... and instead specify the controller in the state definition. You can associate controllers with any/all states, just like you associate a template with each state.

Comment: @SunilD. I'm not sure what you mean by specifying the controller in the state definition.  Do you mean something like:

function ($stateProvider.nws)? Or do I need to specify this in every var state?

Comment: @Alexei  this is the documentation provided on the github and on scotch, it isn't stock AngularJS and so, as I understand it, it requires slightly different syntactical arrangement.

See: 
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

*Resolved*

For anyone who has a similar issue, I tried to define this within a controller.  TOTALLY WRONG.  I hadn't realized that this needs to be defined in the app as a whole, using angular.module.

to anyone who tried to point that out whom I misunderstood.